# Connection refused listing fluentd plugins via in_monitor_agent

Tags: docker, fluentd

I have added following in my conf file (ref - https://docs.fluentd.org/input/monitor_agent )-

```
<source>
  @type monitor_agent
  bind 0.0.0.0
  port 24220
</source>
```

When I run fluentd in a docker container , following log is also reported - >

```
2022-09-21 07:57:22 +0000 [debug]: #0 [monitor_agent_stats] listening monitoring http server on http://0.0.0.0:24220/api/plugins for worker0
```

As per documentation,

> This configuration launches HTTP server with 24220 port

But when I try to run following command in another terminal to list plugins =>

```
curl http://localhost:24220/api/plugins.json
```

I am getting ->

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 24220 after 9 ms: Connection refused
```

Comment: Add `-p 24220:24220` to your `docker run` command for the fluentd container

Comment: great. I will also add an answer for the record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running Fluentd in a container you need to map the ports on host in order to access its api:

```
docker run -p 24220:24220 ...
```

then from host you can run

```
curl http://localhost:24220/api/plugins.json
```

Comment: Also , I was testing this above scenario by running in my local docker , glad it's working locally. Actual error I'm also facing while running this as part of a daemonset readiness probe. My docker image is created via Dockerfile , do we need to expose this port or do we need any other change for this to work properly ?

Comment: the 'EXPOSE' in the Dockerfile is only to inform a user what port to use, it does not actually open a port or so. You map the port on host to make your app available to the outside world. For other containers running on the docker network you don't need to do anything. You directly connect to container:port

Comment: Okay , so ideally if I call `http://localhost:24220/api/plugins.json` from the container , it should return proper response , alright. I'll verify again what else could be wrong.

Comment: ‘localhost’ if you are in the fluentd container. From a different container you need to use the name of the container/service where fluentd runs